# magento 2 clear previous searched string of ui grid after admin logout

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When logging in and logout of magento when you go to search for a customer the previous info is still there - shouldn't this clear after log-out?

[image]

Comment: No it can't, it is default behaviour.

Comment: is there any way to stop it.by doing some tricky thing.

Comment: This may required R & D to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will clear all ui grid past search string when admin logout.

Create file on the below location :

**app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Auth\Logout">
        <plugin name="clear_active_filters_fron_ui_grid" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Controller\Adminhtml\Auth\Logout" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now create a plugin to remove past search result.
**app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Plugin/Controller/Adminhtml/Auth/Logout.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * It will impact on all ui grid past search.
 *
 * @author    vikas kalal
 * @package   General
 */

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Controller\Adminhtml\Auth;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session;

class Logout
{
    const BOOKMARK_NAMESPACE = 'current';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Ui\Model\BookmarkFactory $bookmarkFactory
     */
    private $bookmarkFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Ui\Model\BookmarkFactory $bookmarkFactory
     * @param Session $authSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Ui\Model\BookmarkFactory $bookmarkFactory,
        Session $authSession
    ) {
        $this->bookmarkFactory = $bookmarkFactory;
        $this->authSession = $authSession;
    }

    /**
     * Before Admin Logout Plugin
     *
     * @param  \Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Auth\Logout $subject
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function beforeExecute(
        \Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Auth\Logout $subject
    ) {
        $currentAdminUserId = $this->getCurrentUserId() ?? '';

        if ($currentAdminUserId != '') {
            $bookmarkCollection = $this->bookmarkFactory->create()->getCollection();
            $bookmarkCollection->addFieldToFilter('identifier', self::BOOKMARK_NAMESPACE);
            $bookmarkCollection->addFieldToFilter('user_id', $currentAdminUserId);

            $bookmarkCollection->walk('delete');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Current Admin User
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCurrentUserId()
    {
        return $this->authSession->getUser()->getId();
    }
}
```